# Where is the changelog for 3.5? where is the list of added removed files?

Tags: filters, codex, wordpress-version

This: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changelog/3.5 is not a changelog. 
This: http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5 gives a few changes, etc, but no list of files added and removed.  Where might I find a list of 'breaking changes'?  Actions and Filters that work differently?

Comment: Just follow the links on the pages you mentioned and find http://core.trac.wordpress.org/query?status=closed&milestone=3.5

Comment: That isnt a changelog, either.  I dont see any file listings.  Please reopen this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use GitHub. WordPress has [an official (view-only) GitHub repository](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress), and GitHub has an excellent comparison feature.

Here's [the GitHub comparison of WordPress 3.4.2 vs 3.5](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/compare/3.4.2...3.5).